# Collections which increase number of occurrences instead of adding duplicate

Tags: java, collections

Does exist any collection which stores only unique strings, but count how many times this string was added? 
So every time, when I try add the same string/item again, number of items remain the same but numbers of occurrence of given item will increase?

Comment: Something like [CountedSet](http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/apidocs/opennlp-tools/opennlp/tools/util/CountedSet.html)

Comment: @luk2302 CountedSet is reprecated, better soultion is to use Multiset from Google Guava

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is not such build in collections, but you can simply achieve that by using `Map` collection:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
String sample = "foo";
if (map.containsKey(sample))
    map.put(sample, map.get(sample) + 1);
```

You can also use solution from external library, for example `Multiset` from `Google Guava`:

```
Multiset<String> multiset = HashMultiset.create();
String test = "foo";
multiset.add(test);
multiset.add(test);
multiset.add(test);
System.out.println(multiset.count(test));
```

with output:

```
3
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `HashMap` and wrap some code around it:

```
public class CounterMap<K> {

    private final Map<K, Integer> internalMap = new HashMap<K, Integer>();

    public void increment(K key) {
        initKeyIfNew(key);
        Integer oldValue = internalMap.get(key);
        Integer newValue = oldValue + 1;

        internalMap.put(key, newValue);
    }

    public int getCount(K key) {
        initKeyIfNew(key);
        return internalMap.get(key);
    }

    private void initKeyIfNew(K key) {
        if (internalMap.get(key) == null) {
            internalMap.put(key, 0);
        }
    }

}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
    CounterMap<String> myCounterMap = new CounterMap<String>();
    myCounterMap.increment("hello");
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UniqueStringCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean takeUserInput = true;
        HashMap<String, Integer> uniqueStringMap = new HashMap<>();
        int counter = 0;

        System.out.println("Welcome. To close the program type exit.");
        System.out.println();

        do {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter the unique string");

            String userInput = scan.next();

            if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
                takeUserInput = false;
                scan.close();
            }

            System.out.println();

            if(!userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {

                if(uniqueStringMap.containsKey(userInput)) {
                    counter = uniqueStringMap.get(userInput);
                    uniqueStringMap.put(userInput, ++counter);
                    continue;
                }

                counter = 0;
                uniqueStringMap.put(userInput, ++counter);
            }

        } while(takeUserInput);

        if(!uniqueStringMap.isEmpty()) {
            for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : uniqueStringMap.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("String " + entry.getKey() + " was added " + entry.getValue() + " times.");
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println("Bye bye.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8:

```
 Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
```

When adding a string, do:

```
 map.merge(s, 1, Integer::sum);
```

What this does is add the string `s` and set the value to `1` if it wasn't there yet.  If it was there already, then it takes the current value and the new value you're adding (1 again) and sums them, and puts that back into the map.